# Node JS MongoDB POST Error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

When I try to post to the DB it's showing Error: 'Cannot POST /api/postCampaign' and POST http://127.0.0.1:50945/api/postCampaign 404 (Not Found). I am trying to store data in mongodb database. This code used to work and the mongoose was connected modulus database but after sometime I am trying to redo the code but the modulus.io is not available anymore, so I changed the connect URI. Not sure if there's anything else I am missing

See my codes

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Database connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myappdatabase');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Database Schema / Model
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var campaignSchema = new Schema({
    goalAmount: String,
    campaignTitle: String
});

var Campaign = mongoose.model('Campaign', campaignSchema);

//Routes
app.get('/startCampaign', function(req, res){
        res.sendfile('./public/views/start-campaign.html');
});

app.post('/api/postCampaign', function(req, res) {

    Campaign.create({
        goalAmount : req.body.goalAmount,
        campaignTitle: req.body.campaignTitle,
        done : false

    });
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('App listening on port' + port);
```

MainController.js

```
appTitan.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    // Signup form
    $scope.form = 'signup';

    $scope.switchForm = function(newForm){
        $scope.form = newForm;

    };

    // Start camapaign
    $scope.startCampaignData = {};
    $scope.createCampaign = function(){
        $http.post('/api/postCampaign', $scope.startCampaignData)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
}]);
```

form page

```
<form action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="goal_amount">How much money would you like to raise?</label>
        <input type="text" name="goal_amount" id="goal_amount" ng-model="startCampaignData.goalAmount">
        <select name="goal_amount" id="goal_amount">
            <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="campaign_title">What's the tile of your campaign?</label>
        <input type="text" name="campaign_title" id="campaign_title" ng-model="startCampaignData.campaignTitle">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="goal_amount">Choose a category</label>
       <select name="campaign_category" id="campaign_category">
            <option value="">Choose a category</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button ui-sref="form.stepTwo">CREATE</button>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="createCampaign()">Submit Test</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to make an HTTP request to the database. That's not even possible. You should make a request to your Node server which in turn should write data to DB.

Try to send your request to this endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/api/postCampaign`

Comment: I've added that to both server.js post and angular post but it returns: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and Error: null

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you've changed. I think that the code from your question will work if you only change your API url from `http://127.0.0.1:50945` to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @poohitan. The mongoose.connect URI I sent is just a sample. Where I am actually trying to store the data is mongodb://<myusername>:<mypassword>@123456.mlab.com:222288/x‌​xxxxx. Do I still need to change the API url?

Comment: apologies I have solved the issue. Just realised that I didn't run the server. But your answer lead me to understand that, Thanks